# Multilingual Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, multilingual, analyzer, stop-words, stemming

I'm indexing a bunch of documents in different languages and as far as I understand, I can specify which analyzer to use for each document at index time in one of of the document's field by using an _analyzer mapping:

see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/analyzer-field.html

In essence, a French document while have a language field sets to "french" that will indicate Elasticsearch that it needs to apply French stemming rules and strip French stop words.

Now do I have to specify an analyzer at query time so that Elasticsearch can apply the same stemming rules to the query before actually processing it? If so, then that's a bit of a bummer because I would like to be able to search the whole index, eventually providing a "should" clause favoring documents of a certain language over others.

What I don't know is, does Elasticsearch build multiple queries by applying every analyzers that has been used so far in the index or not. If it doesn't, the only solution I see is to split documents according to their language as different types and then fire several queries in parallel and have some sort of sink function on the client that would merge results and sort them by their score. But, even though I could send a bulk query (to limit network roundtrips), that solution is clearly not optimal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can define separate analyzers for indexing and for searching:

```
 "my_field":{
    "type":"string",
    "index_analyzer":"my_index_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer":"my_search_analyzer"
 }
```

You can also specify default analyzers in the index settings - here is real life example:

```
"settings":{
    "number_of_shards":5,
    "number_of_replicas":1,
    "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
            "default_index":{
                "type":"custom",
                "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                "filter":[
                    "trim",
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                ]
            },
            "default_search":{
                "type":"custom",
                "tokenizer":"keyword",
                "filter":[
                    "trim",
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to explicitly specify the _analyzer field